# Broken Hyperlinks when reseting section on part

Tags: hyperref, links

this seem very basic but i've already tried lots of thing without any success.

This is the tex that i am working on, and im compiling it in LuaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}



% Linguagem
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}



%% Table of contents
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    % remove subsubsection from toc



% Multicols
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{5mm}



% enumitem
\usepackage{enumitem} % modify enumerate index
\setlist[itemize]{left = -9mm}



%% titlesec
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Part customization
\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleformat{\part}
    [block]                         % shape
    {\huge\bfseries\color{Emph}}            % format
    {\thepart\hspace{5mm}{$|$}}         % label
    {5mm}                           % sep
    {\huge\bfseries}                    % before-code
    [\vspace{0.5mm}]
\counterwithin*{section}{part} % Reset section on part



% Maths
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{bm} % Boldmath

\newcommand\BM[2][align*]{{\large\boldmath\bfseries%
    \begin{#1}
        #2
    \end{#1}%
}}



% Colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{Emph}{ blue!40!white}
\colorlet{Background}{white!5!black}

\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}



% mytitle and myauthor
\newcommand\mytitle{{my title}}
\newcommand\myauthor{{my author}}



% title, author and date
\title{\bfseries\color{Emph}\mytitle}
\author{\myauthor}
\date{\today}



% hyperref
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    % Links customization
    hidelinks=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=red!25!white,
    % PDF customization
    pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,
    pdftitle=\mytitle,
    pdfauthor=\myauthor
    % fix hyperref links
    hypertexnames=false
    destlabel=false,
    plainpages=false,
    naturalnames=false
}



% subsubsection customization
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{(\roman{subsubsection})}



\begin{document}


\maketitle


% Table of Contents

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{} % remove title

\section*{Conteúdo}
\begin{multicols}{2} \tableofcontents \end{multicols}


\newpage



\part{Background}



\newpage



\part{Topologia Elementar na Reta $\mathbb{R}$}
\label{topologia elementar na reta r}

\section{Vizinhança $V_{\epsilon}$}
\label{vizinhanca}


\section*{Pontos:}
\label{pontos}


% Majorante e Minorante
\begin{multicols}{2}
    
    \section{Minorante}
    \label{minorante}
        
    \section{Majorante}
    \label{majorante}

\end{multicols}


% Infimo e Supremo
\begin{multicols}{2}

    \section{Infimo Inf}
    \label{Infimo}
    
    \section{Supremo Sup}
    \label{Supremo}

\end{multicols}


% Minimo e Maximo
\begin{multicols}{2}
    
    \section{Minimo Min}
    \label{minimo}
    
    \section{Maximo Max}
    \label{maximo}

\end{multicols}


% Interior e Exterior
\begin{multicols}{2}
    
    \section{Interior Int}
    \label{interior}
    
    \section{Exterior Ext}
    \label{exterior}
    
\end{multicols}


\section{Ponto de Acumulação}
\label{ponto de acumulacao}


\section{Fronteira Fr}
\label{fronteira}
    
\section*{Conjuntos:}
\label{conjuntos}

\section{Limitado}
\label{conjunto limitado}

\begin{multicols}{2}

    \section{Aberto}
    \label{conjunto aberto}
    
    \section{Fechado}
    \label{conjunto fechado}

\end{multicols}

% Feixe e Ponto de Acumulação
\begin{multicols}{2}

    \section{Feixe $\overline X$}
    \label{feixe}

\end{multicols}



\newpage



\part{Indução Matemática}
\label{inducao matematica}


\section{Indução por Igualdade}
\label{inducao por igualdade}


\section{Indução por Desigualdade}
\label{inducao por desigualdade}



\newpage



\part{Sucessões}
\label{sucessoes}


\section{Sucessão Monótona}
\label{sucessao monotona}

\begin{multicols}{2}

    \subsection{Crescente}
    \label{sucessao monotona crescente}
    
    \subsection{Decresente}
    \label{sucessao monotona decrescente}

\end{multicols}

\section{Sucessão Limitada}
\label{sucessao limitada}

\section{Sucessão Convergente}
\label{sucessao convergente}

\section{Demonstrações para Sucessões}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\BM[flalign*]{
&
    X \text{ é \hyperref[sucessao convergente]{convergente}}
\implies &\\&
\implies
    X \text{ é \hyperref[sucessao limitada]{limitada}}
&
}

\BM[flalign*]{
&
    X \text{ é \hyperref[sucessao monotona]{monotona} e \hyperref[sucessao limitada]{limitada}}
\implies &\\&
\implies
    X \text{ é \hyperref[sucessao convergente]{convergente}} 
&
}

\end{multicols}


\newpage



\part{Limites}



\newpage



\part{Continuidade em $\mathbb{R}$}




\end{document}
```

Everything seem in place but the output pdf have lots of links in the wrong place i've already tried fixing hyperref with the following fixes:

- hypertexnames=false
- destlabel=false
- plainpages=false
- naturalnames=false

And even through hypertexnames=false alone previously fixed this problem in other files, in this one it seems to be useless.

Comment: You are resetting sections at \part, and so their number is no longer unique. Use `\renewcommand\theHsection{\thepart.\thesection}` after loading hyperref.

Comment: Great! that worked, i knew i had to change the way hyperref referenced section but i didn't even know i could just do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @UlrikeF, Adding `\renewcommand\theHsection{\thepart.\thesection}` just after `\hypersetup{...}` solves the problem